# "I would rather have done it myself"

Tags: modal-verbs

> I’d rather do it myself.
>   I’d rather have done it myself.
>   (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, p.108)

Is there any regret in the second sentence for not having done it, or is it neutral?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regret is implied.

The *would have ... done* construction implies a counterfactual—for some reason you could not do it yourself—and the *rather* states that you wanted to do it yourself. Consequently you must have been disappointed in some respect.